# How can I auto-fill a subtitle file with the known text I was reading?

Tags: subtitles

Suppose I subtitle a video of myself reading a story. I can use software like gaupol to insert subtitles into a .srt file at particular times. But I shouldn't have to retype the whole story, given I was reading it off the screen when I made the video!

Is there a way to auto-fill the .srt with the text I already have?

Comment: Does gaupol have an option to grab text from a file?

Comment: No— should it? It's easy enough to do the timings with gaupol, but idk how to get the text there.